# Is there a way to make a multiselection in Autocomplete (Angular4+)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to make a multi selection on filtered items by the auto complete.
Inspired from the following [tutorial](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qybdokkpdmb?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html)
I tried this code:

The component :

```
 <form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" multiple>
      <mat-checkbox>
        {{ option }}
     </mat-checkbox> 
     </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I added  tag to enable selection but it does not work. Once I filter and select one option the menu closes and the checkbox doesn't even get checked.
 Is there a way to make a multiselection in Autocomplete?
Thank you !!

Answer (score 45):

[Angular Material documentation for chips](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) includes a nice example of how to get started with a multiple selection autocomplete:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Basically, you have a chip list bound to a list and an text input that allows to search within an autocomplete list.

```
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * @title Chips Autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'chips-autocomplete-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-autocomplete-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['chips-autocomplete-example.css'],
})
export class ChipsAutocompleteExample {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = false;
  separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  fruitCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredFruits: Observable<string[]>;
  fruits: string[] = ['Lemon'];
  allFruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];

  @ViewChild('fruitInput') fruitInput: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()));
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

The code is pretty straightforward (filter based on text input after each typed character, remove an item from the list etc.). Of course, this should be tweaked to your needs (e.g. once you select an item, it should be filtered out for next autocomplete results).

Comment: Do you know how to keep the drop down open so it doesn't close after one selecttion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-mat-chip?file=src/app/chips-autocomplete-example.html

Comment: @Flash Any solutions yet for the dropdown not to close?

Comment: You could use ngx mat select search. It uses mat-select component and add one search box too. Work like mat-select with textbox to search.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search npm package.

Answer (score 25):

This is a little late to the party but I found an excellent stackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sx79hu?embed=1&file=app/multiselect-autocomplete-example.html) . Reproducing the code here, written by the owner:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select Users" aria-label="Select Users" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="userControl">
  <mat-hint>Enter text to find users by name</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" [value]="selectedUsers">
        <div (click)="optionClicked($event, user)">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="user.selected" (change)="toggleSelection(user)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                {{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

<br><br>

<label>Selected Users:</label>
<mat-list dense>
    <mat-list-item *ngIf="selectedUsers?.length === 0">(None)</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of selectedUsers">
        {{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class User {
  constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname: string, public selected?: boolean) {
    if (selected === undefined) selected = false;
  }
}

/**
 * @title Multi-select autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'multiselect-autocomplete-example',
  templateUrl: 'multiselect-autocomplete-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['multiselect-autocomplete-example.css']
})
export class MultiselectAutocompleteExample implements OnInit {

  userControl = new FormControl();

  users = [
    new User('Misha', 'Arnold'),
    new User('Felix', 'Godines'),
    new User('Odessa', 'Thorton'),
    new User('Julianne', 'Gills'),
    new User('Virgil', 'Hommel'),
    new User('Justa', 'Betts'),
    new User('Keely', 'Millington'),
    new User('Blanca', 'Winzer'),
    new User('Alejandrina', 'Pallas'),
    new User('Rosy', 'Tippins'),
    new User('Winona', 'Kerrick'),
    new User('Reynaldo', 'Orchard'),
    new User('Shawn', 'Counce'),
    new User('Shemeka', 'Wittner'),
    new User('Sheila', 'Sak'),
    new User('Zola', 'Rodas'),
    new User('Dena', 'Heilman'),
    new User('Concepcion', 'Pickrell'),
    new User('Marylynn', 'Berthiaume'),
    new User('Howard', 'Lipton'),
    new User('Maxine', 'Amon'),
    new User('Iliana', 'Steck'),
    new User('Laverna', 'Cessna'),
    new User('Brittany', 'Rosch'),
    new User('Esteban', 'Ohlinger'),
    new User('Myron', 'Cotner'),
    new User('Geri', 'Donner'),
    new User('Minna', 'Ryckman'),
    new User('Yi', 'Grieco'),
    new User('Lloyd', 'Sneed'),
    new User('Marquis', 'Willmon'),
    new User('Lupita', 'Mattern'),
    new User('Fernande', 'Shirk'),
    new User('Eloise', 'Mccaffrey'),
    new User('Abram', 'Hatter'),
    new User('Karisa', 'Milera'),
    new User('Bailey', 'Eno'),
    new User('Juliane', 'Sinclair'),
    new User('Giselle', 'Labuda'),
    new User('Chelsie', 'Hy'),
    new User('Catina', 'Wohlers'),
    new User('Edris', 'Liberto'),
    new User('Harry', 'Dossett'),
    new User('Yasmin', 'Bohl'),
    new User('Cheyenne', 'Ostlund'),
    new User('Joannie', 'Greenley'),
    new User('Sherril', 'Colin'),
    new User('Mariann', 'Frasca'),
    new User('Sena', 'Henningsen'),
    new User('Cami', 'Ringo')
  ];

  selectedUsers: User[] = new Array<User>();

  filteredUsers: Observable<User[]>;
  lastFilter: string = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredUsers = this.userControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | User[]>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : this.lastFilter),
      map(filter => this.filter(filter))
    );
  }

  filter(filter: string): User[] {
    this.lastFilter = filter;
    if (filter) {
      return this.users.filter(option => {
        return option.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          || option.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      })
    } else {
      return this.users.slice();
    }
  }

  displayFn(value: User[] | string): string | undefined {
    let displayValue: string;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((user, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          displayValue = user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
        } else {
          displayValue += ', ' + user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
        }
      });
    } else {
      displayValue = value;
    }
    return displayValue;
  }

  optionClicked(event: Event, user: User) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.toggleSelection(user);
  }

  toggleSelection(user: User) {
    user.selected = !user.selected;
    if (user.selected) {
      this.selectedUsers.push(user);
    } else {
      const i = this.selectedUsers.findIndex(value => value.firstname === user.firstname && value.lastname === user.lastname);
      this.selectedUsers.splice(i, 1);
    }

    this.userControl.setValue(this.selectedUsers);
  }

}
```

Comment: doesn't work too well; if you try to autocomplete after selecting some users, you get nothing, also if you clear out the autocomplete text, it still shows some as selected etc.

Comment: Search not working after selecting multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Ng2-select](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/):

```
   <ng-select [virtualScroll]="true" #select [items]="items" [multiple]="true" bindLabel="name" placeholder="items..."
          formControlName="myFormCOntrolName">
        </ng-select>
```

It is styled using angular material. The virtualScroll option isn't well documented at present, but is very fast for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Ng2-select, try the multiple one, https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/, let me know if this is what you want.

In general, there's no good standard for multiple selection.

Comment: Thank you in fact I have to use only Angular Materials for the project I am working on