# Add selected items to ng-select with multiple and typeahead

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-ngselect

I'm using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) to select multiple values from a large list that is remotely loaded depending on what the user types in the box. Here are my requirements:

1. Tags added dynamically
2. Dropdown is not displayed for already selected values. It is only for typeahead of available, unselected values.

Here are the problems that I've run into so far:

- Selected tags do not get displayed if not part of the `items` list.
- Using the tag objects as an array with `[(ngModel)]` makes `ng-select` treat it like the value doesn't exist at all. `ng-select` seems to only use IDs for `[(ngModel)]` when `[mutiple]=true`, as opposed to the selected object when `[multiple]=false`
- The `tagsInput$` observable doesn't get fired if `[isOpen]=false`

I have verified that `tagsService` is operating correctly.

### Current View:

```
<ng-select [items]="tags$ | async"
           bindValue="name"
           [loading]="tagsLoading"
           [typeahead]="tagsInput$"
           [multiple]="true"
           [isOpen]="tagsOpen"
           [searchFn]="filterSelectedTags"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedTagIds"></ng-select>
```

### Current Controller:

```
class TagFormComponent {

  public tags$: Observable<Tag[]>;
  public tagsLoading: boolean;
  public tagsInput$: Subject<string>;
  public tagsChanger$: Subject<Tag[]>;
  public selectedTags: Tag[];
  public selectedTagIds: number[];
  public tagsOpen: boolean;

  constructor(private tagService: TagService) {

    this.tagsInput$ = new Subject<string>();
    this.tagsChanger$ = new Subject<Tag[]>();
    this.tagsChanger$.subscribe( tags => {
      this.selectedTagIds = tags.map(t => t.id);
      this.selectedTags = tags;
    });
    this.tags$ = concat(
      this.tagsChanger$,
      this.tagsInput$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap( () => {
          this.tagsOpen = true;
          this.tagsLoading = true;
        }),
        switchMap(q => this.tagService.search(q).pipe(
          catchError( err => { this.tagsLoading = false; console.error(err); return of([] ); }),
          tap( () => this.tagsLoading = false)
        ))
      )
    );

    this.tagsChanger$.next(this.assetGroup.tags);
  }

  public matcher(a: any, b: any): boolean {
    return !!a && b && a.id === b.id;
  }

  public filterSelectedTags(_q: string, item: Tag) {
    return !this.selectedTagIds.includes(item.id);
  }

  public tagAdded() {
    this.tagsOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this. I don't think `[items]` should be async.  [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)

Comment: Why not? `tags$` is an observable.

Comment: In the documentation the type for `[items]` is `Array<any>`. Not `Observable<Array<any>>`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why there's the async pipe there.

Comment: The async pipe only declares how angular should support your array in the template. It has no bearing on the original type, as declared by the package.

Comment: I think your code is correct, you just need to remove bindValue="name"

Comment: Could you please create a stackblitz example. Could not get it running with your provided code.

Comment: @MehyarSawas This question is over four years old. This may not even be relevant anymore. I'm not currently using Angular so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in "hideSelected" property of the ng-select to hide already selected items.

As for "Selected tags do not get displayed if not part of the items list", looks like you have to preload already selected items. They should always be added to the "items" list. Because of "hideSelected" they will not be shown in dropdown anyway.
So component should first load existing items by their IDs and add them to "items" list, then component has to load items according to the typeahead and add them to the "items" list. This way existing items will always be available for ng-select.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using `mat-autocomplete` in combination with `mat-option`.
See complete examples for this [here on the material-angular components website](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples).

Or for multi-select you can combine `mat-autocomplete` with `mat-option` and a `mat-chip-list`.
See complete examples for this [here on the material angular components website](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples)

See also a similar question with suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49131094/1697459)

In case none of those examples suffice your needs you can maybe elaborate and I could add more details to my answer.