# Angular autocomplete, keep the list open after selecting one for multiple selections

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

I've been working trying to do an autocomplete dropdown. It's fairly similar as this one :

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chips-autocomplete

However, as on the demo, it's really clunky when you need to select multiple, you need to lose focus of the input form then get on it again to get the list displayed. I was wondering if there was a way to to not lose the list.

There were solutions a few years ago about instantly reopening the dropdown, but it doesn't feel like it's how it should be, I thought about losing focus too (so if you click back in, the list displays instead of having to click out then in again), then again, it doesn't feel like the solution either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411655/9283313